# How to remove yellow highlight bars on indent in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VSCode, I get these yellow highlight squares whenever I have indents. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.